# First element JSONArray

Tags: java, android

I try make app with book and in my opinion i found error in this book
We can read in this book this:

> This line reads the "weather" table, accessing the first element of
>   the array containing the description of the weather conditions of the
>   day and illustrating the icon

and they give this line:

```
JSONObject weather =
               day.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
```

from this class

```
private void convertJSONtoArrayList(JSONObject forecast) {
      weatherList.clear(); 

      try {

         JSONArray list = forecast.getJSONArray("list");


         for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject day = list.getJSONObject(i); 

            JSONObject temperatures = day.getJSONObject("temp");


            JSONObject weather =
               day.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);


            weatherList.add(new Weather(
               day.getLong("dt"), 
               temperatures.getDouble("min"), 
               temperatures.getDouble("max"), 
               day.getDouble("humidity"), 
               weather.getString("description"), 
               weather.getString("icon"))); 
         }
      }
      catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

and here is error in my opinion(they underline 3 and 4 element, not 1st):

```
1 {
2 "city": {
3 "id": 5128581,
4 "name": "New York",
5 "coord": {
6 "lon": -74.005966,
7 "lat": 40.714272
8 },
9 "country": "US",
10 "population": 0
11 },
12 "cod": "200",
13 "message": 0.0102,
14 "cnt": 2,
15 "list": [{ 
16 "dt": 1442419200,
17 "temp": {
18 "day": 79.9,
19 "min": 71.74,
20 "max": 82.53,
21 "night": 71.85,
22 "eve": 82.53,
23 "morn": 71.74
24 },
25 "pressure": 1037.39,
26 "humidity": 64,
27 "weather": [{
28 "id": 800,
29 "main": "Clear",
30 "description": "sky is clear",       <-- they underline this
31 "icon": "old"                        <-- and this
32 }],
33 "speed": 0.92,
34 "deg": 250,
35 "clouds": 0
36 }, { 
37 "dt": 1442505600,
38 "temp": {
39 "day": 79.92,
40 "min": 66.72,
41 "max": 83.1,
42 "night": 70.79,
43 "eve":81.99,
44 "morn": 66.72
45 },
46 "pressure": 1032.46,
47 "humidity": 62,
48 "weather": [{
49 "id": 800,
50 "main": "Clear",
51 "description": "sky is clear",
52 "icon": "01d"
53 }],
54 "speed": 1.99,
55 "deg": 224,
56 "clouds": 0
57
```

Comment: if you think there is error in the book, then ask the author of the book, not us. We didn't write it. Also you didn't ask any questions. Do you have any questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Book example is correct and can be explained as below. 
In the above code snippet, it is reading for each array element the following values:

- min and max key from temp object whose value correspond to 1st object as:

  - 71.74
  - 82.53
- Humidity key whose value correspond to 1st object as:

  - 64
- description and icon key from weather object whose value correspond to 1st object as:

  - "sky is clear"
  - "old"

Answer (score 3):

There is no error in the book. It's just JSON parsing.

```
JSONObject weather =
               day.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0);
```

the above live will give you a JSONObject

```
{
28 "id": 800,
29 "main": "Clear",
30 "description": "sky is clear",       <-- they underline this
31 "icon": "old"                        <-- and this
32 }
```

Comment: so speed, deg and cloud is a 2nd element of array "weather" ?

Answer (score 1):

The book is  correct.

Note that the first item on the array is neither the description nor the icon. Instead, it's a whole json object:

```
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "sky is clear",
"icon": "old"
}
```

Once they get this object using `getJSONObject(0)`, they access its description and icon entries (which are unordered, by the way, since json entries within an object are unordered).

Comment: so speed, deg and cloud is a 2nd element of array "weather" ?